# Error #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s) in Mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1241

I just try following query:

```
SELECT *, 
      (
       SELECT count(*) 
       FROM users 
       where users.email=calls.email
      ) as ureg, 
      (
       SELECT sum(qty) 
       FROM product 
       where product.owner in 
          (SELECT * 
           from users 
           where users.email=calls.email)
      ) as pop 
FROM calls 
order by calls.data desc 
LIMIT 0,20
```

but I get following error :

```
#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

How should I fix my query?

Edit:
by changing 
`SELECT * from users where users.email=calls.email` 
to 
`SELECT id from users where users.email=calls.email`

it works because the query searches for product.owner in bunch of `id`s that exist in users

Comment: Could you please format the query with linebreaks?

Comment: by change: SELECT * from users where users.email=calls.email

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
where product.owner in (SELECT *
```

`product.owner` is one column, so the subquery should return one column (whatever corresponds to `product.owner`).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 SELECT calls.*, count(users.*) as ureg, sum(twons.qty) as pop 
 FROM calls 
 INNER JOIN users ON users.email=calls.email
 INNER JOIN towns ON towns.id = users.town 
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--you have to correct this to your table column names
  order by data desc 
  LIMIT 0,20
```

- you have to correct this `ON towns.id = users.town` to your tables names