# #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql

i cannot find whats the issue here and why i am getting the error of #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `User` `t`
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT cv.relatedId
    FROM CustomValue cv
    WHERE (cv.customFieldId=9 AND (cv.fieldValue = '1')) OR
          (cv.customFieldId=8 AND (cv.fieldValue = '1'))
    GROUP BY cv.relatedId
    HAVING count(*) > 1
) tblcv
    ON tblcv.relatedId = t.id
WHERE (firstName LIKE '%Jea%') AND (keywords like 52,53,54)
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s) in Mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945867/error-1241-operand-should-contain-1-columns-in-mysql)

Comment: `keywords like 52,53,54`? Did you mean to use `in` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use `(keywords like 52,53,54)`.

You can use `keywords in (52,53,54)`

or `keywords like '52,53,54'`.

**Edited:**

Or maybe you want this;)

```
(find_in_set('52', keywords) or find_in_set('53', keywords) or find_in_set('54', keywords))
```

Or this `keywords regexp '52|53|54'`, it all depends on your requirement.